# Is there a limit on how many columns can be appended using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to append data to a google sheet from my python script. Each row has 49 values (49 columns to be updated for each row). However, when I run my code, it only updates 40 columns for each row and discards the last 9 values.

I've searched on google to find anything related to this, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Here's my code:

```py
RANGE_NAME = 'Left Hand Tray' # the name of the sheet.
data_to_upload = [['FAN_ASSEMBLY', 'Right Nest', '2019-03-27 19:24:35', '142.968002', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['FAN_ASSEMBLY', 'Left Nest', '2019-03-27 19:26:18', '94.480003', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['FAN_ASSEMBLY', 'Right Nest', '2019-03-27 19:28:41', '143.207993', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['FAN_ASSEMBLY', 'Left Nest', '2019-03-27 19:31:55', '193.112000', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
body = {
    'majorDimensions': 'ROWS',
    'values': data_to_upload
}

request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME, body=body, valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED')
response = request.execute()
```

The last values for each data row does not get uploaded. Here is the response I get:

```py
{'spreadsheetId': <the_spreadsheet_id>, 'tableRange': "'Left Hand Tray'!A1:AW4121", 'updates': {'spreadsheetId': <the_spreadsheet_id>, 'updatedRange': "'Left Hand Tray'!A4122:AN4125", 'updatedRows': 4, 'updatedColumns': 40, 'updatedCells': 160}}
```

You can see in the response, it says the sheet has columns till AW but in the updates part, you can see it only uploaded till column AN.

Comment: I tested your code and `print(len(data_to_upload[0]))` outputs `40`, not `49`.

Comment: You're right, there's another issue with my code. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data_to_upload matrix only has **40** not *49* elements on each row  as @glhr mentioned.

You are not passing the google sheet limits, that you can see here: https://gsuitetips.com/tips/sheets/google-spreadsheet-limitations/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to. Check the size of your `data_to_upload` array:

```
print("Rows:",len(data_to_upload))
print("Columns:",len(data_to_upload[0]))
```

Returns:

```
Rows: 4
Columns: 40
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@glhr/55399477)

Note that `tableRange': "'Left Hand Tray'!A1:AW4121",` means exactly that... the range of your whole table (4121 rows, 49 columns).

`'updatedRange': "'Left Hand Tray'!A4122:AN4125"` indicates the range of the table which was updated (4 rows, 40 columns), which matches the size of your input data.